# Do we need data-imputation, multiple-imputation and imputation tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There seems to be a fair amount of redundancy in the tags containing imputation in them. As of this writing, I observe the following distribution of imputation tag usages:

- data-imputation: 160
- multiple-imputation: 617
- imputation: 4

Clearly multiple imputation is just one (very popular) variety of imputation, so perhaps we only need the tags imputation and multiple-imputation. To me, data-imputation appears to be somewhat redundant: I don't know what one would impute if not data!

Comment: The easiest solution is to manually change 4 instances of [imputation] to [data-imputation]; the empty tag will disappear after one day. No moderator action is needed for that, which is a big advantage (moderators here are often reluctant to proceed with any tag changes, AFAIK partially because those cannot easily be reversed).

Comment: @amoeba Thanks for the tip! I was concerned that "going rogue" and doing so without attempting to reach consensus among other CV users would be frowned upon. I'll hold off until others have had a chance to weigh on.

Comment: Note that creating a tag does not require any "consensus" whatsoever, and once a tag is created it is likely to be used every now and then. Therefore I would argue that tidying up minor tags does not *necessarily* require a discussion either; of course any large-scale changes should be discussed.

Comment: I wanted to look at the 4 questions with the imputation tag and realized that there are none: [imputation] is a synonym of [data-imputation] (since 2013) and if you try to look at these 4 questions you get redirected to the data-imputation with 160+4=164 questions... Looks confusing to me, but I guess that's how synonyms work on SE.

Comment: Update: I read this FAQ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710 about synonym tags. It seems that if we edit these 4 questions in any way, then the tag will be automatically replaced by the "master" tag (and again, if no questions with [imputation] are left, it will disappear). Alternatively, a moderator can "merge" these two tags, leading to the same effect. At the moment they are not "merged", but are simply synonyms.

Comment: Current situation looks fine in that if you choose "imputation" as a search tag, you get redirected to all the "data-imputation" questions, and if you begin to add imputation as a tag to a question, you see that "data-imputation" predominates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we only need the tags [imputation] and [multiple-imputation]. To me, [data-imputation] appears to be somewhat redundant

As I've already written in the comments above, [imputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/imputation) is since 2013 a synonym of [data-imputation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-imputation). However, it is a *non-merged* synonym, and that's why 4 questions that were originally taged with [imputation] still remain to be tagged with this (obsolete) tag. This can clearly be confusing, as demonstrated by your question. That's why I suggest to merge all our non-merged tag synonyms: [Should all our non-merged tag synonyms be merged (or removed)?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2790)

I am posting this answer in order to draw attention to this merging issue.

Comment: I'll merge them soon if no-one comes up with a good reason not to.

Comment: I've done it now.

Comment: Looks like this issue is resolved!