# How can one find tags with no wiki excerpts? How can one sort tags by recency?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags, tag-excerpt, tag-wiki

In tags, there are options to see them by name or popularity or recency. For the first two, you can go through all the tags, but for recency, you can only see the most recent. It would be useful to be able to see all the tags sorted by recency.

It would also be useful to be able to see tags that need Wiki summaries or full Wikis, but this doesn't seem to be possible.

Comment: Asking for the ability to sort by date should probably be done on [meta.SE]; that would need to be done by the developers & would be SE-wide. There is a [data query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/431621/most-used-tags-without-excerpts) for tags w/o excerpts.

Comment: Thanks!  I did not know about data queries at all.  However, the query didn't work quite right - for instance, I ran it and found "inferential-statistics" on the list. But it has both an excerpt and a full wiki.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem w/ the query is. The SQL code is quite simple.

Comment: I don't know either (I don't know SQL at all, but this does look straightforward).  But, you can see that inferential-statistics (not surprisingly) does have a full wiki.

Comment: [inferential-statistics] is an unmerged synonym. Itself, it does not have a wiki excerpt. As I must have said 100 times before, [WE SHOULD BE MERGING ALL OUR UNMERGED SYNONYMS](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2790) [that are older than say 3 months] because it only creates confusion. Cc @gung. Peter, you are a mod; can you help doing that?

Comment: I don't know how to merge synonyms.  I didn't see an option to do that on the page for inferential-statistics.

Comment: If you want to try it out and see how it works, you could start with the two existing unmerged synonyms on Meta: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?filter=merge&tab=newest. I am obviously not familiar with the moderation interface but I imagine it should be straightforward... @gung should know how it works.

Comment: I just merged them (& a whole bunch of others).

Comment: @gung Great! I don't see them merged but perhaps some time is needed until it gets updated.

Comment: @gung Ah, I realized that by "them" you must have meant inferential-statistics & inference (I do see them merged). I thought you meant the two unmerged ones on Meta, but I guess you did not touch those yet (at least they still look unmerged as of now). Anyway, thanks for bringing this forward.

Comment: @amoeba, TBH, meta.CV didn't even occur to me. I see there were 2 synonyms that were unmerged here. I have merged them now.

Comment: @gung Cool. It's just that I mentioned them to Peter in a comment right above your comment saying "I just merged them", hence my confusion.

Comment: @amoeba, lol. Evidently, I didn't read that closely.

Comment: But I just (7:15 PM Eastern, Feb 20) ran the query again and inferential-statistics is still there.  I guess the database is still updating?

Comment: It's updated once per week.

Comment: You can find all tags without excerpts or wikis by using [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/810957/tags-without-a-wiki-or-excerpt).